# Python string issue replacing a / with \/\

Tags: string, python-2.7, replace

I have a string with `/`

I need it to be `\/\`

Right now I have

```
string = test/text.replace('\/\')
```

and this throws an error.  Any thoughts on how to achieve the desired outcome?

Comment: I also tried `str.replace('\\/\\')` and that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Your usage of the `replace` method is incorrect.  As per the help, the `replace` method is:

> Help on method_descriptor:
>
> `replace(...)`
>
> ```
> S.replace(old, new[, count]) -> string
>
> Return a copy of string S with all occurrences of substring
> old replaced by new.  If the optional argument count is
> given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.
> ```

The method takes at least two arguments.

(2) You'd need to escape backslashes.

As such, the following might achieve what you need:

```
>>> s = "a/b"
>>> s.replace("/", "\\/\\")
'a\\/\\b'
>>> r = s.replace("/", "\\/\\")
>>> print r
a\/\b
```

Comment: Yes I found the that going "\\/\\" with a print gives the desired out put, but when passing this var around and concatenating with other strings it keeps the \\/\\ 


for instance 
`'title': '007: Tomorrow Never Dies \\/\\ 007: The World is Not Enough'}`

Comment: If it helps I am using orchestrate.io, and in python i noticed that when you set the variables to use `\/\` instead it is keeping the double backslashes used to escape.

Comment: What you are seeing is the `repr` of the string.  Observe the answer carefully, you would notice that the string is displayed in two different ways -- the first instance of the replacement shows the `repr` which causes the backslashes to appear escaped.